# Configure Bind9 master zone to accept all third levels of domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, debian-wheezy

I tried for several hours configuring a Bind server on Debian 7 in order to obtain this:

*.example.local.

I need that every third or fourth level for "example.local" (for example: abc.example.local, one.two.three.example.local, etc...) to go to a specific IP Address (ie.: 192.168.100.200).

I really can't find a way to obtain this, everytime the server answers me with a SERVWARN telling it can't find example.local.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is easy as writing this two lines in your forward lookup zone file:

```
@                       IN      A       192.168.100.200
*.example.com.          IN      A       192.168.100.200
```

Watch the endpoint after the .com

Comment: And add in the zone too : @ IN A 192.168.100.200 to have example.local working